# Extensible Asp.net MVC web grids , with the ability to do sort, filter & paging on the database level

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

Currently I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application, and on the index views I have wrote the sorting & paging code manually , which gives me the ability to control how the paging and sorting works. so in my case if I have 10,000 records and the paging size is 50 then only the 50 records will be retrieved from the database, so my current approach can be considered extensible. 
But currently I am looking to use web grids because it can save me time and efforts. But I need to know if there are any web grids that have the following main features:-

1. Provide Ajax-base sort, filter and paging
2. All the sort, filter and paging need to be done on the database level.
3. The ability for the users to change the number of records displayed, such as show me 100 records, 200 records , etc
4. The ability to easily change the look and feel of the web grid.

So can anyone advice on available web grids that have the above 4 main features?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same requirements for an upcomming project and found [Kendoo UI Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index) during my research. If you follow the link you will find a demo including the sourcecode.
Some features according to their [webpage](http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid):

- Responsive and Adaptive HTML5 Grid
- Page, Sort, Filter or Group Data in ASP.NET MVC Grid
- MVC Grid Templates

Comment: but the grid does not provide any filter capabilities based on the columns

Comment: have you tried the following example? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row

Comment: Kendo UI Core does not include the Grid component unfortunately.